# Auto increment primary key value is always 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, oledb

I was trying to add a new row to the database using the below code.

Even though the `Rundef` table has a primary key that should auto increment, it's value is always zero. Why does this happen?

```
Private oRunDefDS As DataSet
Dim oDR As DataRow = oRunDefDS.Tables("RunDef").NewRow()
```

The design of the `Rundef` table:

[image]

Comment: Could you display the design of your particular table? It is plausible that the auto increment (identity in SQL Server) isn't set up correctly.

Comment: @DKyleo I've updated the question with that.Hopes that it helps

Comment: Okay, open up the Identity Specification of your RunID column within Column Properties, and check whether is listed as Yes or No.

Comment: It's set to yes with seed and step equal to 1

Comment: Unless you've inserted a default value or binding of 0, your identity key should work.

Comment: Are you looking at the RunID before or after saving a record to the database?

Comment: @hvd I Checked value RunID in in Visual Studio jus after calling NewRow() function. One more thing I noticed is even though increment seed in db is 1, when I checked auto increment seed of the ODR it's 0.

Comment: @MuhammedThabjeel you didn't post any code that inserts data to the database. `NewRow()` constructs a *new empty DataRow object*

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos is correct, all this is doing is inserting a row into the `DataTable` not in the datatable of your DB. Have you tried using SSMS and just inserting a record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new row in code it hasn't been inserted into the database yet. This means the database engine hasn't assigned it's incremental ID and gives it a default of 0 instead.

Insert the record to the database and the id should be updated automatically, though you might need to re-read the row to get the data back depending on the data access too you are using.

If this were not the case then your code could create many new rows for internal use only, but there would need to be a reservation on the IDs used. If you never saved these new row to the database you would end up with lots of gaps in your incremental IDs.

Comment: You probably mean `inserted`. `Commit` always refers to transactions when talking about databases

Comment: I think NewRow() should initialize the Id field by itself right?

Comment: Correct, but the NewRow object is only in memory not in the database. It's only when it is saved there is the incremental ID applied.

Comment: @MuhammedThabjeel no, that's just a row constructor for a DataTable that may have *nothing* to do with the database*. Identity values are generated by the *database*, not the code

Comment: For some other tables call to NewRow() returns a row with incremented id value even without inserting

Comment: @MuhammedThabjeel definitely not. Maybe there's some custom code that modifies the content before inserting. Or **negative** values are used when you have datatables with relations, to provide a temporary ID for related records. Those values will be replaced with real ones when the dataset is saved to the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry for troubling you. But when i call NewRow() function for some other table like this **Dim oDR As DataRow = oCableRecDataSet.Tables("CableDef").NewRow()** and check the datarow it's value is nonzero and everytime it's changing

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, edited Commit->Insert to make it simpler.