# The fractional part of the provided time value overflows exception SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, oledb

I was trying to add a new row to a table using msoledbsql provider and dataset. But On calling update function I'm getting an exception:

> The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column. Increase bScale in DBPARAMBINDINFO or column scale to correct this error

How can I resolve this issue?

```vb
Private oRunDefDS As DataSet
oRunDefDS.Clear()
' create the Data Row
Dim oDR As DataRow = oRunDefDS.Tables("RunDef").NewRow()
' populate the datarow with values
AddDRofRunDef(RunDef, oDR)
' add the datarow to the dataset
oRunDefDS.Tables("RunDef").Rows.Add(oDR)
```

---

```vb
Private Sub AddDRofRunDef(ByVal RunDef As DBResults, ByRef oDR As DataRow)
    ' Add a new row to Dataset from a class object.
    ' Copy Results definition for a particular RunID
    ' from DBResults Class to RunDef table of database ProductionResults.
    With RunDef
        oDR("RunId") = 10
        oDR("RunDateTime") = .RunDateTime
        oDR("LineNum") = .LineNum
        oDR("ProductID") = .ProductID
        oDR("RunNum") = .RunNum
        oDR("ActNumWires") = .ActNumWires
        oDR("OWOWSpec") = .OWOWSpec
        oDR("OWOWTolUpper") = .OWOWTolUpper
        oDR("OWOWTolLower") = .OWOWTolLower
        oDR("OperID") = .OperID
        oDR("SampleOffset") = .SampleOffset
        oDR("Blank1") = 1
        oDR("Blank2") = 2
        oDR("Blank3") = 3
        oDR("Blank4") = 4
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The error message tells you what to do: "Increase [...] column scale to correct this error". What effort have you made to do that? There only appears to be one column that could be at issue so have you tried to find out what the current scale is and what it can be increased to?

Comment: @jmcilhinney _RundateTime_ column has data type datetime2(0). datetime2 should accept any date right?

Comment: No it does not... looking at your [**last post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763617/auto-increment-primary-key-value-is-always-0) this field is `datetime2(0)`...

Comment: @Codexer yeah. But I'm inserting the date _#8/9/2018 05:04:27 PM#_ which does not have milliseconds part

Comment: If you really were inserting that value then it seems unlikely that the error message would be talking about the fractional part of the time. Are you sure that you're not just seeing a text representation that looks like that but the underlying value actually does have a fractional part?  How are you setting `RunDef.RunDateTime`?

Comment: @Muhammed Thabjeel `DateTime2(0)` will store datetime in this format i.e YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. Look at your current value above, it doesn't match and is an overflow.

Comment: @Codexer You're saying that 'PM' should be removed? But it'll convert it automatically right?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Rundef.RunDateTime= Date.Now

Comment: If you're using `Date.Now` then that absolutely contains fractional seconds. It may not be displayed that way in the debugger or wherever else but it's there.  `Date.Now.ToString()` won't show it because the default format only shows whole seconds but try using `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff")` and you'll see it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the scale of the column but rather remove the fractional part of the data then here are a couple of methods that may be of use:

```vb
Public Function Truncate(source As Date) As Date
    With source
        Return New Date(.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second)
    End With
End Function

Public Function Truncate(source As TimeSpan) As TimeSpan
    With source
        Return New TimeSpan(.Days, .Hours, .Minutes, .Seconds)
    End With
End Function
```

You could even write those as extension methods if you wanted to:

```vb
Public Module DateTimeExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Truncate(source As Date) As Date
        With source
            Return New Date(.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second)
        End With
    End Function

End Module

Public Module TimeSpanExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Truncate(source As TimeSpan) As TimeSpan
        With source
            Return New TimeSpan(.Days, .Hours, .Minutes, .Seconds)
        End With
    End Function

End Module
```

and then call them directly on a value of that type, e.g.

```vb
With RunDef
    oDR("RunId") = 10
    oDR("RunDateTime") = .RunDateTime.Truncate()
```